# When abroad, ATM or Bureau?

Tags: foreign-exchange, travel, atm

If I am travelling abroad, what it likely to give me a better exchange rate?

1. Exchange Bureau
2. Pull large sums of cash from an ATM

Note; I've been told that using ATMs is actually cheaper if you do it properly

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot of the country you are going to.

- some countries, the best exchange rate is with street dealers. Some countries, this is illegal (but typically, then it works even better).
- some countries, ATM is cheaper
- some countries, changing in a bank is cheaper
- it's nearly always more expensive if you exchange in the airport (or the main train station)

It also depends on your credit/debit card details. Some cards include fee-free withdrawal, and some cost an arm and a leg if used at a different bank.

So, a general answer is not possible.